# Do I am possible monitoring traffic net the mi App Services in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

How do I am monitoring traffic net the my App Service in Azure? I need monitoring traffic net for request between App Services and database.
Everything is the same resource group and region

Comment: I need to know the source IP and destination IP in each request

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to include this question. How do I know that all the network traffic between my appservices and the database goes through the Azure internat network and does not go to the Internet? All my resources are in the same region of Az

Comment: I need all network traffic to be directed by the Azure backbone

Comment: What about Application Insights?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej From the Application Insights I cannot visualize that information.
I need to see a tracert with the source IP and the destination IP of all the requests that are made to confirm that the traffic is routed through the Az trunk.